# Remove multiple elements from an array EXTJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

I'm aware of the traditional ways to remove elements from the array, but im wondering if there is a any pro tip/method in EXTjs that would remove selected items in an array.

```
var array = 
 [{id:"week", address : "something"},
  {id: "month", address : "something2"},
  {id:"year", address : "something23"},
  {id:"ext-comp-12", address : "something23"},
  {id:"ext-comp-13", address : "something23"},
  {id:"ext-comp-132", address : "something23"}
 ]
```

I want to remove elements: last-week,last-month, before-date from the list. I cannot use the indexes to refer to the position of the remove elements as they are dynamically created. this `array.filter(e => e.id== "week");` doesn't work for me.
Know any other methods?thx

Comment: I still see the length of items as is, and displayd w/o removing the filtered object though it returns an object filtered.

Comment: If I run that in the console (after fixing the syntax errors) it returns an array with 1 item. What more are you expecting?

Comment: yes but it does not remove from the list, check the length, it still shows 6, but if I do a pop on the array, i see the element removed and length as 5

Comment: `array.splice(array.findIndex(f => f.id == "week"),1);`

Comment: @Redu: thats good, how can i do for multiple items(removing "week", "month" and"year")? I dont want to depend on the index, as they may vary..

Comment: I suppose you have to execute `array.splice(array.findIndex(f => f.id == "theProtpertyValueToSelectTheItemToDelete"),1);` once for each item that you want to delete

Comment: @Redu:not sure what you mean by"theProtpertyValueToSelectTheItemToDelete"

Comment: I mean you have to execute that instruction one for each like `array.splice(array.findIndex(f => f.id == "week"),1); array.splice(array.findIndex(f => f.id == "month"),1); array.splice(array.findIndex(f => f.id == "year"),1);`

Comment: tried: array.splice(array.findIndex(f => f.id == "year" || f.id == "month"),1), it removes only month in this case..:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleaner way is to replace the orginal array with the filtered one because this is the functional approach: `array = array.filter(e => e.id== "week");`.

To remove multiple items from the original array you must iterate and use one of "splice", "erase", "remove"... ecc from javascript Array or Ext.Array.

```
var toRemove = array.filter(e => e.id == "week");
toRemove.forEach(e => Ext.Array.remove(array, e));
```

Another approach could be to use an ExtJs collection instead of the javascript array. Both `Ext.data.Store` and `Ext.util.MixedCollection` have methods to bulk remove items.

**Old answer**

The ExtJs alternative to array splice is `Ext.Array.erase`:

> Removes items from an array. This is functionally equivalent to the splice method of Array, but works around bugs in IE8's splice method and does not copy the removed elements in order to return them (because very often they are ignored).

Ex: `Ext.Array.erase(array, array.findIndex(f => f.id == "week"), 1);`

Comment: the splice worked for me too..the question was how to apply (either 'Array.erase' or 'Array.aplice' )to remove multiple items from the array. the above just removes one item..

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get the focus of the question, I will edit